# How to consume external websocket API in Apache Camel since ahc-ws deprecate?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, java-websocket, asynchttpclient

ahc and ahc-ws (Async Http Client) components have been deprecated in Apache camel version 3.16: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17667.

Is there an alternative for [ahc-ws](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/ahc-ws-component.html)? The component was very easy to use to consume external websockets API.

Other libraries like [Jetty](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/websocket-component.html), [Undertow](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/undertow-component.html), [Atmosphere](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/atmosphere-websocket-component.html),  don't seem to offer this kind of features. I have not been able to configure them and the documentation remains unclear. They only provide the server part.

For the [websocket-jsr356](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/websocket-jsr356-component.html) component, I can't configure the component to consume a WebSockets over SSL API (wss). The library seems to support only classic websocket (ws).

I looked for alternatives on the camel doc, examples on github but I didn't find anything.

Is there a viable alternative to ahc-ws to consume external websocket APIs simply with camel?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not deprecated yet. There is just a suggestion for that. ahc-wss is very useful currently and there is no viable alternative for the same. websocket component requires tedious tweaking of secure storage parameters and is just kills the purpose of wss. I hope they don't deprecate ahc-wss without a proper replacement though.